# If I wanted to modify task switching in OSX

Tags: macos, applescript

I am looking to modify the way that task switching happens on OSX so that I can link two windows together. The main reason for this is that I am using Cinch, which allows for Windows 7 like snap on OS X.

When I setup two windows side by side, it is usually because I want to see both of them at the same time. I want to be able to link those two windows together so that when I task switch to one, the other is also brought to the front.

Can I accomplish this through an applescript or will I need to make a program similar to Cinch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to purely use Applescript you would do something like this :

```
set app1 to "Google Chrome"
set app2 to "TextEdit"
repeat
    tell application "System Events"
        set a to name of first process whose frontmost is true
        if a is equal to app1 then
            tell application app2 to activate
            tell application app1 to activate

        end if
    end tell
    delay 0.5
end repeat
```

However, this is not very efficient. You will need to continuously run this in the background. Although it wouldn't take up much, if any, resources since it's so simple.

For it to run in the background you will need to edit its .plist file and add :
Application is agent (UIElement) => true

Your alternative is to make a Cocoa-Applescript or actual Cocoa-Obj-C app. This would be a little harder, but would be the best way to do it.

Comment: That script would make Chrome unusable, as you would have at most half a second after activating it before TextEdit steals the focus. Honestly, doing it with Cocoa will probably be pretty hard too. I don't know if you could do it without a plugin which gets run in the applications you are targeting.

Comment: I've slightly tweaked the script. It's not pretty by any means, but it solves the problem.